# ¿ How to create a select query that displays data if they match at least one word?

Tags: sql

Example :

I have a column in my database that keeps a book genres ... and most have something in its genre as " Action , adventure, horror " .

I have 3 books, one is adventure , romance .

Another is action, horror .

And the last one is action , science fiction .

Suppose, I want to search all books that have the word "action" ... The Query would have to return the last two books, because their gender have the word " Action " .

How could I do this in SQL ?

Comment: The correct way to do this is to have a table with a genre_id & a  *single* genre and another table with multiple book_ids for each genre_id - Multiple values in a single column rapidly becomes a nightmare to manage and breaks normalization rules.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help guys !! I want to give points but I still can not .. also wanted to know who was the " Troll" that gave a -1 to my question. ¬¬

Comment: I didnt down vote and now just upvote to even things. But to be honest your question wasnt very well prepared, and some ppl are just picky. You should include db schema and sample data in a text format not just text. please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Add dbms used, you've got some product specific answers already...

Comment: The correct answer is not to break first normal form. Don't put multiple values into a single field.  Use a many-to-one relationship to another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DeadZone say to avoid select `fiction` and `science fiction` just append `,`

In Sql Server you can do something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM books
WHERE ',' + genre + ',' like '%,action,%'
```

The problem is using this `LIKE` wont allow you use `INDEX` so in bigger data table can be a problem.

Comment: Please specify which dbms this is for. (Product specific answer to a question without any dbms specified.)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question given your table, use the LIKE operator.  `WHERE MyTable.Genre LIKE '%action%'`  (The only problems with this would be if some genre keyword contains another keyword.  For example if you have the genres, "fiction" and "science fiction".)

Now for the better way.  Normalize the database.  Create a `Genres` table that contains `Genre_ID` and `Genre_Description` columns.  Then your `Books` table would contain a `Genre_ID` column with a Foreign Key constraint that prevents bad data.  Then you could build a query that joins the two tables and gives you exactly what you want.  This follows best practices with relational databases.  It processes faster than comparing strings.  And it takes up less space.  It is the preferable solution.  Good luck!

Comment: You were fastest. But I have the solution for you science fiction :)